Update from IFlurlClientFactory to IFlurlClientCache - Do I need using around IFlurlClientFactory.GetOrAdd()?
I have recently updated from the old IFlurlClientFactory to the new IFlurlClientCache and thus applied all the required changes.
We were seeing an issue when using the following code:
public class FlurlHttpClient
{
    private IFlurlClientCache ClientCache { get; set; }

    public FlurlHttpClient(IFlurlClientCache clientCache)
        => ClientCache = clientCache;
    
    public string DoCall()
    {
        ...
        
        using (var client = ClientCache.GetOrAdd("ExampleHostName", "http://example.host.com/api"))
        {
            ...
            
            var httpResponse = await client.SendAsync
            (
                new FlurlRequest
                {
                    Content = content,
                    Url = url,
                    Verb = request.HttpMethod,
                }
            );
            
            ...
        }
        
        ...
    }
}

The code would work on a 1-1 call case - aka when a single call came into our API and then used this class, but when multiple calls came into our API and thus used this method at the same time then the httpResponse would NOT be successful..
The ONLY way we found to fix this was by removing the using portion, but I am unsure if this is the correct path to follow or not as it seems like we may be disposing the client before it gets used again - especially in quick succession..
Aka -- do I need to find another way to dispose of the unused client or is that handled in the background now?

No, definitely don't wrap ClientCache.GetOrAdd in a using statement. That  effectively disposes the client at the end of the using block, rendering it unusable for future calls, which defeats the purpose of caching it.
Much like HttpClient doesn't need to be disposed (and usually shouldn't be), neither does FlurlClient.
